# Convert DataFrame of JSON Strings

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

Is it possible to convert a DataFrame containing JSON strings to a DataFrame containing a typed representation of the JSON strings using Spark 2.4?

For example: given the definition below, I'd like to convert the single column in `jsonDF` using a schema that is inferred from the JSON string.

```
val jsonDF = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("""{"a": 1, "b": 2}""")).toDF
```

Comment: If people who downvote would explain why they are down-voting, that would be helpful and encourage a better community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataFrameReader` can read JSON from string data sets. For example using `toDS` instead of `toDF`

```
val jsonDS = Seq("""{"a": 1, "b": 2}""").toDS
spark.read.json(jsonDS).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
+---+---+
```